# Special kind of 3-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, 3-manifolds

Is there an open connected orientable 3-manifold $M$ with the following properties:

1. $M$ admits a complete hyperbolic metric with finite hyperbolic volume.
2. $H_{i}(M,\mathbb{Z})=0$ for any $i>0$.

Comment: Such a manifold would be the interior of a compact orientable 3-manifold $N$.  By half-lives, half-dies we must have $H_1(\partial N) = 0$, so each component of $\partial N$ is a 2-sphere.  Since the hyperbolic metric has finite-volume, it can't have any 2-spheres as a boundary component, so $\partial N = \emptyset$.  It follows that $M$ is closed, so $H_3(M) = \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  Suppose that $M$ is a finite volume oriented hyperbolic three-manifold.  In the closed case, as $M$ is oriented, we have $H_3(M, \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ generated by the fundamental class.  In the open case, $M$ has torus cusps.  Appealing to "one-half lives, one-half dies" we find that $M$ has non-trivial (in fact infinite) $H_1$.

[See Lemma 3.5 of Hatcher's [notes on three-manifolds](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/3M/3Mdownloads.html) for the statement and proof of "one-half lives, one-half dies".]